# Hibernate OneToOne Table join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Learning Hibernate. 
I have the following classes User, Region, Country as follows

```
     public class User {

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;
     @Column(name = "first_name")
     Private String firstName;
     @Column(name = "last_name")
     private String lastName;
     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinTable(name = "user_country_region", joinColumns ={@JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =   "country_id") })
     private Country userCountry;

     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinTable(name = "user_country_region", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "region_id") })
     private Region userRegion;

     //With its respective Getters and Setters 
   }

    public class Country {

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;
     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     //With its respective Getters and Setters 
   }

   public class Region {

     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private int id;
     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     //With its respective Getters and Setters 
   }
```

The problem am facing is hibernate query only returns region and not country. What could be causing this?

Tried getting country and region values as below

```
    System.out.println("Country: "+user.getCountry().getName());
    System.out.println("Region: "+user.getRegion().getName());
```

Response from Hibernate Show sql. Seems missing country details.

```
    Hibernate: 
    select
       this_.id as id1_3_3_,
       this_.first_name as first_na2_3_3_,
       this_.last_name as last_na3_3_3_,
       region2_.id as id1_8_2_,
       region2_.name as name2_8_2_ 
    from
       user this_ 
    left outer join
       user_country_region this_1_ 
       on this_.id=this_1_.user_id  
    left outer join
    region region2_ 
       on this_1_.region_id=region2_.id 
    where
    this_.id=?
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the names of your tables. user_country_region, user_coutnry_region? Are both correct? just to start with the basics?

Comment: Yes they are the same. Fields within the table are as follows user_id, country_id, region_id. This table joins the three.

Comment: just updated the question with how I was trying to initialize user country and region

Comment: It is not an initialization code. Hibernate fetch all data with `User` cause of `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. Please, enable SQL logging and add logs to your question to see how Hibernate fetches data.

Comment: I have updated the question and attached the hibernate SQL response.

Comment: Does this mean  @JoinTable only applies when there exists one foreign key ? i.e user_country table has two country_id and region_id.

Answer (score 1):

It is an invalid mapping. I have this error with Hibernate 5 while create the schema by Hibernate.

```
org.hibernate.boot.spi.InFlightMetadataCollector$DuplicateSecondaryTableException: 
Table with that name [user_country_region] already associated with entity
```

Anyway, if you can use this mapping with your Hibernate version, having such kind of mapping with a join table for two relations is error prone.

Just use this mapping to associate `User` with `Country` and `Region` by foreign key columns.

```
public class User {

     @OneToOne
     private Country country;

     @OneToOne
     private Region region;

   }
```

Comment: Seems no other solutions exist which is strange. Will have to work with this.

Comment: Works when I change from OneToOne to @ManyToMany. How? I have not idea.